# Encryption and Decryption of Video

Tags: python, video, encryption

We are building a Kiosk application, which keeps downloading videos from a web app using a secure SSH tunnel.

The Kisoks can get stolen, and the customer wants the video files encrypted so that no one can steal them. This is because some of the video content is copyrighted from third parties and there are some license obligations which the client has.

The Kiosk has only a web browser, and through a touch screen different users play video.

We would like the video to be encrypted in normal course, but decrypted while playing on the web video player.

We have not decided on any of these things, and are flexible

1) The browser video player
2) The file format

The operating system on Kiosk is a stripped down version of Ubuntu 12.04. And the web application and the application that downloads and updates content from the remote server is Django/Python.

Can you advise the right strategies to go about the encryption/decryption on the fly

Comment: What does it have to do with python?...

Comment: Serious question. Why not encrypt the entire hard drive using something like truecrypt?

Comment: But if you copy the file you lose encryption

Comment: Still waiting for this answer